# Master thesis: asking people to check the math

Tags: support, allowed-questions, asking-questions, questions

My academic advisor quit and the project is now discontinued. Yet, I'm still registered and I intend to hand in the thesis soon. The last time my advisor checked my work was a while ago since then I restructured everything from confusing flow charts towards mathematical equations.

As I am not a mathematics student I'm not well versed in this and I'm worried I have some errors in there. Can I just post "Assessment required: iterative function denotations" or something similar to math.stackexchange.com or should I use another platform for such things?

Comment: I don't foresee a good way for you to accomplish this through MSE, either in whole or through cutting it into parts. Further, I think it would ultimately be worse for you than if you talked to those left in your department for their advice and suggestions. A very reasonable and not-completely-unheard of solution would be for your department to contact someone outside the department to serve as an external examiner/adviser --- things like this sometimes happen, and many mathematicians consider such an act as one of the many aspects of service that they give to the community. Good luck.

Comment: You note that you are "not a mathematics student," so it might be useful to know what kind of studies you are pursuing.  The fine granularity of Questions and Answers on Math.SE works against having any substantial part of your thesis "checked" there.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The question you propose is probably not a good fit for MSE.  Questions on MSE should be narrowly focused and of broad interest to the community of mathematics students and mathematicians who comprise the user base of MSE.  You are essentially asking someone to proofread your thesis (or, at least, the mathematically intensive portions of that thesis), which is neither narrowly focused nor of general interest.

---

What follows is off-topic for this website (though your question might be on-topic at [Academia SE](https://academia.stackexchange.com/)), but I'll offer my opinion:

It is unfortunate that you are no longer working with your advisor, as the kind of proofreading you are requesting really is part of the work of an advisor.  Your first step should probably be to reach out to your advisor and ask for help or, barring that, find someone else in your department who is willing to advise you long enough to finish your degree.  Indeed, you are probably going to have to get *someone* to agree to sign your completion paperwork in the place of you advisor; in an ideal world, that person ought to be helping you with your work.

Alternatively, if you need someone to check your math, I would recommend having a chat with someone in the mathematics department of your institution.  You ought to be able to hire someone to help you out (and you should be paying for their services—what you are requesting is a pretty big ask).

Comment: Thank you for your response! I agree, it is a lot to ask. However, is it legitimate if I divide it all up in highly trivialized sub-problems of 3 or 4 lines, and then phrase the question as: "Correct math notations for iterative equation" etc.?

Comment: That would certainly address the issue of focus.  However, you also need to address the issue of interest.  Would these trivial sub-problems be of interest to the community here?  Moreover, if you were to do that, you would also need to first do your basic research, and try to determine whether or not the question already had been asked and answered here.